# How to rename columns of a nested dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a python function that cleans up my dataframe(replaces whitespaces with _ and adds _ if column begins with a number):

These dataframes were jsons that have been converted to dataframes to easily work with them.

```py
def prepare_json(df):
    df = df.rename(lambda x: '_' + x if re.match('([0-9])\w+',x) else x, axis=1)
    df = df.rename(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'), axis=1)
    return df
```

This works for simple jsons like the following:

```
{"123asd":"test","test json":"test"}

Output:

{"_123asd":"test","test_json":"test"}
```

However when i try it with a  more complex dataframe it does not work anymore.

Here is an exampe:

```
{"SETDET":[{"SETPRTY":[{"DEAG":{"95R":[{"Data Source Scheme":"SCOM","Proprietary Code":"CH123456"}]}},{"SAFE":{"97A":[{"Account Number":"123456789"}]},"SELL":{"95P":[{"Identifier Code Location Code":"AB","Identifier Code Country Code":"AB","Identifier Code Logical Terminal":"XXX","Identifier Code Bank Code":"ABCD"}]}},{"PSET":{"95P":[{"Identifier Code Location Code":"ZZ","Identifier Code Country Code":"CH","Identifier Code Logical Terminal":"","Identifier Code Bank Code":"INSE"}]}}],"SETR":{"22F":[{"Data Source Scheme":"","Indicator":"TRAD"}]}}],"TRADDET":[{"Other":{"35B":[{"Identification of Security":"CH0012138530","Description of Security":"CREDIT SUISSE GROUP"}]},"SETT":{"98A":[{"Date":"20181127"}]},"TRAD":{"98A":[{"Date":"20181123"}]}}],"FIAC":[{"SAFE":{"97A":[{"Account Number":"0123-1234567-05-001"}]},"SETT":{"36B":[{"Quantity":"10,","Quantity Type Code":"UNIT"}]}}],"GENL":[{"SEME":{"20C":[{"Reference":"1234567890123456"}]},"Other":{"23G":[{"Subfunction":"","Function":"NEWM"}]},"PREP":{"98C":[{"Date":"20181123","Time":"165256"}]}}]}
```

Trying it out with this i get the following error when trying to write the dataframe to bigquery:

```
Invalid field name "97A". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 300 characters long. with loading dataframe
```

Comment: please add example with expected output... this question is not clear enough

Comment: @adirabargil updated the example. Hopefully its more clear what im trying to do now.

Comment: These are not a dataframes.

Comment: @mozway the jsons are converted to a dataframe prior to applying this function(prepare_json)

Comment: please show the dataframe sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe my solution helps you:

1. I convert your dictionary to a string
2. find all keys of dictionary with `regex`
3. replace `spaces in keys` by `_` and add `_` before `keys start with digit`
4. convert string to the dictionary with `ast.literal_eval(dict_string)`
   try this:

```
import re
import ast
from copy import deepcopy

def my_replace(match):
    return match.group()[0] + match.group()[1]  + "_" + match.group()[2]

dct = {"SETDET":[{"SETPRTY":[{"DEAG":{"95R":[{"Data Source Scheme":"SCOM","Proprietary Code":"CH123456"}]}},{"SAFE":{"97A":[{"Account Number":"123456789"}]},"SELL":{"95P":[{"Identifier Code Location Code":"AB","Identifier Code Country Code":"AB","Identifier Code Logical Terminal":"XXX","Identifier Code Bank Code":"ABCD"}]}},{"PSET":{"95P":[{"Identifier Code Location Code":"ZZ","Identifier Code Country Code":"CH","Identifier Code Logical Terminal":"","Identifier Code Bank Code":"INSE"}]}}],"SETR":{"22F":[{"Data Source Scheme":"","Indicator":"TRAD"}]}}],"TRADDET":[{"Other":{"35B":[{"Identification of Security":"CH0012138530","Description of Security":"CREDIT SUISSE GROUP"}]},"SETT":{"98A":[{"Date":"20181127"}]},"TRAD":{"98A":[{"Date":"20181123"}]}}],"FIAC":[{"SAFE":{"97A":[{"Account Number":"0123-1234567-05-001"}]},"SETT":{"36B":[{"Quantity":"10,","Quantity Type Code":"UNIT"}]}}],"GENL":[{"SEME":{"20C":[{"Reference":"1234567890123456"}]},"Other":{"23G":[{"Subfunction":"","Function":"NEWM"}]},"PREP":{"98C":[{"Date":"20181123","Time":"165256"}]}}]}


keys = re.findall("{\'.*?\': | \'.*?\': ", str(dct))
keys_bfr_chng = deepcopy(keys)


keys = [re.sub("\s+(?=\w)", '_', key) for key in keys]
keys = [re.sub(r"{\'\d", my_replace, key) for key in keys]

dct = str(dct)
for i in range(len(keys)):
    dct = dct.replace(keys_bfr_chng[i], keys[i])


dct = ast.literal_eval(dct)
print(dct)
type(dct)
```

output:

```
{'SETDET': [{'SETPRTY': [{'DEAG': {'_95R': [{'Data_Source_Scheme': 'SCOM', 'Proprietary_Code': 'CH123456'}]}}, {'SAFE': {'_97A': [{'Account_Number': '123456789'}]}, 'SELL': {'_95P': [{'Identifier_Code_Location_Code': 'AB', 'Identifier_Code_Country_Code': 'AB', 'Identifier_Code_Logical_Terminal': 'XXX', 'Identifier_Code_Bank_Code': 'ABCD'}]}}, {'PSET': {'_95P': [{'Identifier_Code_Location_Code': 'ZZ', 'Identifier_Code_Country_Code': 'CH', 'Identifier_Code_Logical_Terminal': '', 'Identifier_Code_Bank_Code': 'INSE'}]}}], 'SETR': {'_22F': [{'Data_Source_Scheme': '', 'Indicator': 'TRAD'}]}}], 'TRADDET': [{'Other': {'_35B': [{'Identification_of_Security': 'CH0012138530', 'Description_of_Security': 'CREDIT SUISSE GROUP'}]}, 'SETT': {'_98A': [{'Date': '20181127'}]}, 'TRAD': {'_98A': [{'Date': '20181123'}]}}], 'FIAC': [{'SAFE': {'_97A': [{'Account_Number': '0123-1234567-05-001'}]}, 'SETT': {'_36B': [{'Quantity': '10,', 'Quantity_Type_Code': 'UNIT'}]}}], 'GENL': [{'SEME': {'_20C': [{'Reference': '1234567890123456'}]}, 'Other': {'_23G': [{'Subfunction': '', 'Function': 'NEWM'}]}, 'PREP': {'_98C': [{'Date': '20181123', 'Time': '165256'}]}}]}
dict
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This seems like a good solution. only thing missing is adding the _ on columns that begin with a number. so ex 95R should become _95R

Comment: Almost. I didnt express it clear enough in the question maybe. But i only need this for the keys. Values should not have whitespaces replaced. But other than that the solution seems to work fine

Comment: it almost works. How can i make it that it only edits the KEYS from the json and not the VALUES?